# I have one process that only write and multiple processes that only read a file. how to allow the N process to read concurrently?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am working on a multi-agent system where one Writer and multiple Reader interact with a file. The Writer update the file, and the Readers read from it. I'm using Python's multiprocessing module, and to speed up things i would like that when the Writer is doing other things, Readers can read concurrently and when the Writer wants to write, he has the priority and hes the only one that can access the file in that moment

```
import multiprocessing
import time

class SharedData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0
        self.condition = multiprocessing.Condition()

    def modify_value(self, agent_id):
        with self.condition:
            print(f"Agent {agent_id} is modifying the value.")
            self.value += 1
            # Notify waiting processes that a modification has occurred
            self.condition.notify_all()

    def read_value(self, agent_id):
        with self.condition:
            # code....
            self.condition.wait()

            # Non-critical section for reading
            print(f"Agent {agent_id} is reading the value: {self.value}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create shared data
    shared_data = SharedData()

    # Create agent processes
    agents = [multiprocessing.Process(target=read_value, args=(shared_data, i)) for i in range(4)]
 agents.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=modify_value, args=(shared_data, i)) )
    # Start the agents
    [agent.start() for agent in agents]

    # Wait for all agents to finish
    [agent.join() for agent in agents]

    # Access the shared data after all agents have finished
    with shared_data.condition:
        final_value = shared_data.value
        print("Final Value:", final_value)
```

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: you want to use either `threading` or `asyncio` and not `multiprocessing`.

Comment: why i cannot use multiprocessing? or in general you suggest to use asyncio

Comment: as per the answer posted. `multiprocessing` is for processor intensive tasks. the question is an i/o task, which is suited to `threading` or `asyncio`.

Comment: You certainly can use multiprocessing. I'm not sure there's a _good_ reason to use it, though.

Comment: ...if you're using multiprocessing, the net effect is basically identical to if you had multiple completely independent programs trying to interact with your file at the same time, and requires the same locking techniques you would use in that scenario.

Comment: See [`fcntl.lockf`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.lockf), which lets you create read locks on a file (multiple can be held at once), or write locks (only one can be held at a time, and not while any read locks are also held) -- basically exactly what you're asking for. I  agree with @D.L that you _shouldn't_ use that technique within a single program (which is a scenario in which much more efficient non-file-based concurrency management techniques are available), though.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy,  why on earth would you advise a new user to use `multiprocessing` for an i/o based task ? we are responsible to guide users correctly.

Comment: @D.L, I'm telling them they _can_. I'm quite explicitly not telling them they _should_ -- indeed, I've repeated explicit caveats about that several times. What they _should_ do is completely abandon the question altogether and use a technique utterly disconnected from what they asked for; but "don't do this" is a matter for commentary, not answers: "you shouldn't do X", while often sound advice, doesn't answer the question "how do I do X?".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy,  i can use a hammer to paint my walls, but i should use a paint brush. it is quite simply the wrong tool in this instance.

Comment: Agreed, fully! But if someone asks "how can I use a hammer to paint my walls?", "here's how you can use a paintbrush" _isn't an answer to that question_.

Comment: @D.L Moreover, we _already have_ lots of Q&A about how to use paintbrushes, so adding more "here's how to use a paintbrush" as an answer that asked how to use a hammer is cluttering up the knowledgebase with content that's already there. If you think the OP is just badly expressing a question about paintbrushes, vote to close as a duplicate of a question that's already answered with a description of how to use a paintbrush!

Comment: so using threads i would do something like: The Writer creats a thread (using asyncio) that write the file but also i need to lock so that the reaers cannot read. when the thread finishes, readers can start read but how i can let multiple readers reading @CharlesDuffy the same file? i need to use again lock so that the writer cannot modify the file while Readers read. but doing so i will block also the other readers since they are using the same lock variable( Readers are process (more cpu bound than I/O bound) because they do also other things. )

Comment: (Mind, we _do_ have a "practical, answerable" [requirement for topicality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), so one can argue that a request is so needlessly impractical as to be off-topic).

Comment: @feedback,  with `asyncio` the code would not need to lock the file, since the process can be `awaited`. with threading, one would have to be more careful (but infact one can `join()` threads too).

Comment: @feedback, ...so, the nice thing about either threading or asyncio is that you have shared memory so you can use native mutexes instead of filesystem locks to control access to shared resources. (Mind, for most purposes I'd strongly suggest using a file layout that's designed for safe concurrency -- a sqlite database, for example, handles most of the hard parts for you -- if it's even remotely possible to do so).

Comment: @D.L, ...eh, `await` may or may not be enough for safety -- depends very much on the details, and whether what you're doing _within_ the mutation operations has any points at which the async scheduler can let another task take over. There's a reason (a good reason!) that the asyncio library has its own mutex types (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html); advising someone not to use them is risky.

Comment: exactly, the libraries (`asyncio` and `threading`) cater for this in their own ways (threading allows for a `threading.Lock()`). which is why they are highly suitable...

Comment: thanks everybody. ill try to study more in depth and publish here the solution

Answer (score 0):

You say, "... and when the Writer wants to write, he has the priority and hes (sic) the only one that can access the file in that moment". You would certainly want the writer to have exclusive control when writing/updating data. Otherwise, the readers would be reading possibly inconsistent data. Conversely, once the readers have control of the shared data the writer should be locked out from making changes to the data. Having the writer being able to write whenever it wants seems to be a bit at odds with this. The writer would have to have some way of getting the readers to stop reading and release their hold on the data immediately. But I believe this needs to be cooperative as we cannot halt the readers processing in some indeterminate state. This seems to require some sort of sharable "stop" variable that the writer can set that causes the readers to terminate their reading as soon as possible.

I have created class `RWLock` (read/write lock). It is instantiated with the number of reader threads/processes. It works as follows:

1. Each reader task (thread or process) is assigned its own `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue` queue.
2. A reader task does a blocking queue `get` call on its queue when it wants to acquire sharable read access to whatever data is being shared. The queues are initially empty and so all the reader tasks initially block.
3. When the writer task wants exclusive access to the sharable data, it "joins" all the queues awaiting for any previous item it has put to each queue has been processed. Since the queues are initially empty, the join requests immediately succeed. When the writer is through writing its data, **it needs to wait until all reader tasks have read and processed the data before writing new data**. So the writer puts to each queue some item that will cause the blocked readers to wake up. Now when the writer issues `join` calls on the queues, these calls will block until the reader tasks call `task_done` on their respective queues.

Thus, we have the readers waiting (by issuing blocking `get` calls on their respective queues) until the writer signals that there is new data (by putting an item on each of the readers' queues) and then the writer waits until all readers have signaled to the writer (by calling `task_done`) that that have processed the data. Then the writer, which has issued blocking `join` calls on the queues, now continues to run to do the next write.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Value, JoinableQueue
from threading import local
import time

class RWLock:
    def __init__(self, num_readers: int):
        """Create a lock that supports a single writer
        and multiple readers, the number of which is specified by
        the num_readers argument."""

        if num_readers < 1 or not isinstance(num_readers, int):
            raise ValueError('num_readers must be a positive integer.')
        self._local_storage = local()
        self._num_readers = num_readers
        self._queue_count = Value('i', 0)
        self._stop = Value('i', 0)
        self._lock = Lock()
        self._queues = [JoinableQueue(1) for _ in range(self._num_readers)]

    def acquire_for_reading(self) -> None:
        """The reader is asking for shared read access to the data."""

        # Assign ourselves one of the queues if we haven't already done so:
        queue = getattr(self._local_storage, 'queue', None)
        if queue is None:
            with self._lock:
                queue = self._queues[self._queue_count.value]
                self._queue_count.value += 1
            self._local_storage.queue = queue
        queue.get()  # wait for writer to have written something

    def release_for_reading(self):
        """The reader is thorugh with shared read access to the data."""
        self._local_storage.queue.task_done()

    def acquire_for_writing(self, immediate=True):
        """Acquire exclusive access to the data. If argument immediate
        is True, the readers are asked to give up access to the data
        as soon as possible."""

        if immediate:
            self._stop.value = 1;

        for queue in self._queues:
            queue.join()

    def release_for_writing(self) -> None:
        """Give up exclusive write access."""

        self._stop.value = 0  # Reset

        for queue in self._queues:
            queue.put(None)

    def is_stop_posted(self) -> bool:
        """A reader calls this function periodically to see if the
        writer wants immediate exclusive control of the shared resourece."""

        return True if self._stop.value else False

### Eaxmple usage ####

def reader(rw_lock, id, shared_data):
    while True:
        rw_lock.acquire_for_reading()
        # Simulate doing a long reading task.
        # Now that we have access for shared reading, we should
        # periodically check if the writer wants excusive control:
        sleep_time = id / 10
        for _ in range(10):
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
            if rw_lock.is_stop_posted():
                break
        print('reader', id, 'done processing', shared_data.value, flush=True)
        rw_lock.release_for_reading()

def writer(rw_lock, shared_data):
    while True:
        rw_lock.acquire_for_writing(immediate=(shared_data.value == 3))
        shared_data.value += 1
        print('wrote', shared_data.value, 'at', time.time(), flush=True)
        rw_lock.release_for_writing()

def main():
    rw_lock = RWLock(3)
    # Shared data:
    shared_data = Value('i', 0, lock=False)
    for id in range(1, 4):
        Process(target=reader, args=(rw_lock, id, shared_data), daemon=True).start()
    Process(target=writer, args=(rw_lock, shared_data), daemon=True).start()
    input('Hit enter to terminate:\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
Hit enter to terminate:
wrote 1 at 1704820185.6386113
reader 1 done processing 1
reader 2 done processing 1
reader 3 done processing 1
wrote 2 at 1704820188.7424514
reader 1 done processing 2
reader 2 done processing 2
reader 3 done processing 2
wrote 3 at 1704820191.8461268
reader 1 done processing 3
reader 2 done processing 3
reader 3 done processing 3
wrote 4 at 1704820192.1564832
reader 1 done processing 4
reader 2 done processing 4
reader 3 done processing 4
wrote 5 at 1704820195.2668517
reader 1 done processing 5
reader 2 done processing 5
reader 3 done processing 5
wrote 6 at 1704820198.3816946
reader 1 done processing 6
... etc.
```

Note that the writer in general has to wait approximately 3 seconds between writes since the third reading task sleeps for a total of 3 seconds in simulating its reading processing. But when the 3rd record has already been processed the writer next calls `acquire_for_writing` with the *immediate* argument set to `True` and then gets to write its 4th record almost immediately (it depends on how frequently the reader tasks check for the "stop" flag being set).

**Programming Notes**

The above `RWLock` class was written to work with either multiprocessing or multithreading tasks. If you know you will be using multithreading, then some efficiency can be gained by replacing the queues and locks with those supplied by the `multithreading` module. You can also replace the class's attributes that are implemented as sharable (across processes) `multiprocessing.Value` instances with plain old `int` variables:

```py
from threading import Thread, Lock
from queue import Queue
from threading import local
import time

class RWLockMultiThreading:
    def __init__(self, num_readers: int):
        """Create a lock that supports a single writer
        and multiple readers, the number of which is specified by
        the num_readers argument."""

        if num_readers < 1 or not isinstance(num_readers, int):
            raise ValueError('num_readers must be a positive integer.')
        self._local_storage = local()
        self._num_readers = num_readers
        self._queue_count = 0
        self._stop = 0
        self._lock = Lock()
        self._queues = [Queue(1) for _ in range(self._num_readers)]

    def acquire_for_reading(self) -> None:
        """The reader is asking for shared read access to the data."""

        # Assign ourselves one of the queues if we haven't already done so:
        queue = getattr(self._local_storage, 'queue', None)
        if queue is None:
            with self._lock:
                queue = self._queues[self._queue_count]
                self._queue_count += 1
            self._local_storage.queue = queue
        queue.get()  # wait for writer to have written something

    def release_for_reading(self):
        """The reader is thorugh with shared read access to the data."""
        self._local_storage.queue.task_done()

    def acquire_for_writing(self, immediate=True):
        """Acquire exclusive access to the data. If argument immediate
        is True, the readers are asked to give up access to the data
        as soon as possible."""

        if immediate:
            self._stop = 1;

        for queue in self._queues:
            queue.join()

    def release_for_writing(self) -> None:
        """Give up exclusive write access."""

        self._stop = 0  # Reset

        for queue in self._queues:
            queue.put(None)

    def is_stop_posted(self) -> bool:
        """A reader calls this function periodically to see if the
        writer wants immediate exclusive control of the shared resourece."""

        return True if self._stop else False

### Eaxmple usage ####

class SharedValue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

def reader(rw_lock, id, shared_data):
    while True:
        rw_lock.acquire_for_reading()
        # Simulate doing a long reading task.
        # Now that we have access for shared reading, we should
        # periodically check if the writer wants excusive control:
        sleep_time = id / 10
        for _ in range(10):
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
            if rw_lock.is_stop_posted():
                break
        print('reader', id, 'done processing', shared_data.value, flush=True)
        rw_lock.release_for_reading()

def writer(rw_lock, shared_data):
    while True:
        rw_lock.acquire_for_writing(immediate=(shared_data.value== 3))
        shared_data.value += 1
        print('wrote', shared_data.value, 'at', time.time(), flush=True)
        rw_lock.release_for_writing()

def main():
    rw_lock = RWLockMultiThreading(3)
    # Shared data:
    shared_data = SharedValue()
    for id in range(1, 4):
        Thread(target=reader, args=(rw_lock, id, shared_data), daemon=True).start()
    Thread(target=writer, args=(rw_lock, shared_data), daemon=True).start()
    input('Hit enter to terminate:\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Was this answer helpful?

Answer (score -2):

the question is asking about **concurrency** which is achieved in 3 ways of which two are suited for I/O tasks. Reading and writing data is generally an I/O task.

So you would use either:

1. `threading` - multiple threads
2. `asyncio`   - like threading but with more control

The third method is `multiprocessing` which is for processor intensive tasks, which unfortunately the question example used.

here is an asyncio example:

```py
import time
import asyncio

async def count():
    print("One")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("Two")

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(count(), count(), count())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    s = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(main())
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s
    print(f"{__file__} executed in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds.")
```

and here is a treading example:

```py
import logging
import threading
import time

def thread_function(name):
    logging.info("Thread %s: starting", name)
    time.sleep(2)
    logging.info("Thread %s: finishing", name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO,
                        datefmt="%H:%M:%S")

    logging.info("Main    : before creating thread")
    x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(1,), daemon=False )
    logging.info("Main    : before running thread")
    x.start()
    logging.info("Main    : wait for the thread to finish")
    # x.join()
    logging.info("Main    : all done")
```

generally speaking, threading is sufficient and avoids the need for `async` organisation. But async gives more control to the programmer.

here are the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrency.html

Comment: I very much disagree that asyncio is "like threading but with more control"; there are very major differences (f/e, concurrent behavior when the GIL is released) that have nothing to do with the level of "control". And the examples aren't focused on the OP's file-centric question -- there are specific techniques that need to be used to safely do atomic appends to a file.

Comment: To be clear, if you're simplifying the question to "how do I concurrently generate data in one place and process it in concurrently-running workers?", then that question would be a duplicate of things we already have in the knowledgebase. To make it _not_ be a duplicate, we need to accept the OP's premises.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy,  this is a large topic and the question is at a beginners level (knowing the difference between i/o and processor) so i deliver the answer in a suitable format for the question level...   BTW. i quite like that description because that is how i think of it when ignoring the GIL.

Comment: this is not an answer for the question asked here.